# System of many non-linear (quadratic) first order O.D.E. (numerical strategy or simplification)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization

I have a large system (N>100) of equations

$\frac{d\vec{P}}{dt}= A(t) + B(t) \vec{P} + \vec{P}^T C(t) \vec{P}$

where $\vec{P}$ is a vector of N functions of the variable t.

What is the correct name of these kind of equations in Mathematical Ecology?

What do you guys suggest to do to **numerically** solve this equation as efficiently as possible? I am not familiar at all with numerical packages or strategies.

PS1: I am currently using Mathematica method NDSolve (with the option "EquationSimplification"->"Solve" which I am not sure what it does).

PS2: For sake of completeness, the actual structure of this quadratic form is

$\frac{dP_i}{dt}= \sum_j [\alpha^1_{ij}(t) P_i(1-P_j)+\alpha^2_{ij}(t) (1-P_i)P_j+\alpha^3_{ij}(t) P_i P_j+\alpha^4_{ij}(t) (1-P_i)(1-P_j) ]$

Has this form a name? 
It is pretty common in semiconductor physics (non-equilibrium kinetic equation for Fermionic open quantum systems).